# Creating a route with JSON data given user input

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am looking to use JSON data to create a route using the Google Maps API and extract JSON data that will be displayed onto a text field that includes "distance" and "duration". I would like to have to text fields that will reverse geocode and send a request to the Google Map API. Here is an example code I'm using:

```
    // Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request      returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// parse the JSON response into an object
// Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

// Each element in statuses is a single status
// represented as a NSDictionary
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {
  // You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary
  // This will print the tweet and username to the console
  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"text"], [[status objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);
}
```

Rather than it print onto the screen I would like for this to print onto a text field while gathering specific data from the JSON data. I would also like to be able to reverse geocode.

Comment: Just a remark: Consider using iOS's own [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of `SBJSON`.

Comment: I actually tried using NSJONSerialization in a tutorial that I found and kept getting back xcode errors about an @ in the wrong place.       http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979201/xcode-google-map-navigation/3979229#3979229